# "iamRoleStatements should be an array of objects" when trying to add multiple Roles to a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I'm trying to add 2 roles for my Lambda function buy i'm getting this error :

**iamRoleStatements should be an array of objects, where each object has Effect, Action, Resource fields. Specifically, statement 1 is missing the following properties: Resource**

My code:

```
InsertImageDB:
  handler: index.lambda_handler
  module: InsertImageDB
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
      Resource:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - imageLibraryTable
          - Arn

    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - sns:*
      Ressource:
        Ref: DetectLabelTopic
```

Note that i'm using the **serverless-iam-roles-per-function** which allows to add seperate Roles to each function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is that you're using Cloudformation [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) within the Serverless Framework [function section](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/).

Specifically:

```
Resource:
    Fn::GetAtt:
      - imageLibraryTable
      - Arn
```

And

```
Ressource:
    Ref: DetectLabelTopic
```

You don't want to use [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) here, but rather an ARN using serverless [variables](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/)

Check out [role names](https://github.com/functionalone/serverless-iam-roles-per-function#role-names) in the [serverless-iam-roles-per-function docs](https://github.com/functionalone/serverless-iam-roles-per-function)